# Theme problems with Kdenlive

Tags: themes, kde, kdenlive

I am having a problem with themes in Kdenlive.

I'm trying to use the Wonton soup theme in Kdenlive so I've downloaded the `.colors` file from  http://kde-look.org. Then I go to System tools => preferences => KDE system configuration => Application Appearance => and browse to the file that I have downloaded.

Then I am able to launch Kdenlive and to select the Wonton Soup theme. Apparently the theme was applied correctly, but I noticed that some buttons and palettes do not take the theme, keeping a white background. This is a dark theme, so the font colors tend to be white. So, in the buttons not affected by the theme it is impossible to read what is the button.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just installed the QT configurations package. Everything works fine now.